# Fatal Exception - unable to instantiate activity - real application class is null

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to build and run an app in Android Studio 2.2.2 that does work in Eclipse.   When I try to debug it (on a Samsung Galaxy tab 4)  I get:  (*BTW is there any way to get this to come out more readably in StackOverflow?*)

> I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle... I/System.out: debugger
>   has settled (1484) I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android
>   package is com.xxxxxxx.remote, real application class is null.
>   W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                     Process: com.xxxxxxx.remote, PID: 1925
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxxx.remote/com.xxxxxxx.remote.RemoteControlActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.xxxxxxx.remote.RemoteControlActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.xxxxxxx.remote-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxxxxxx.remote.RemoteControlActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.xxxxxxx.remote-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2634)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)

...etc...
I've "xxxxx"'ed out a proprietary name.  What do **real application class is null** and  **No instant run dex files added to classpath**  mean?  Also I see the reference to "**Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo**" in a lot of similar questions -  what does it mean?

The activity it can't find is declared in the manifest as...

```
     <activity android:launchMode="singleTask"   
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowNoTitle="false"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:name=".RemoteControlActivity">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I can't even hit a breakpoint at the beginning of the Activity, so how do I debug this?

Comment: You can disable InstantRun and see if the problem persists.

Comment: One check that I have found useful is CTRL+clicking on the activityname (.RemoteControlActivity in this case). If the IDE doesn't automatically open the class, then there is a problem with name resolution.

Comment: @Doron Yakovlev-Golani Disabling Instant Run fixed it -  I can nowbreakpoint at _OnCreate()_.    Based on your comment I read the documentation on Instant Run and I STILL don't understand what it does, but apparently it was enabled.  If you'd like to post this as an Answer I can give you a rep point and mark the question "answered".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Didn't find class on path: DexPathList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435658/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable InstantRun and see if the problem persists.