# problems with main actvity

Tags: java, android, xml, runtime, mobile-application

whenever i try to launch the app it crushes so my logcat displays this

> logcat

```
2019-02-22 03:08:15.442 7022-7022/com.example.whatsappclone E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.whatsappclone.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:731)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
                ... 12 more
2019-02-22 03:08:16.142 7022-7022/com.example.whatsappclone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.whatsappclone, PID: 7022
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whatsappclone/com.example.whatsappclone.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-02-22 03:08:16.145 7022-7022/com.example.whatsappclone E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.whatsappclone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.whatsappclone-8dz68hsI19AuFX5Ytae9HA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                ... 6 more
```

so the line 44 of the main activity which appears to have the error but i cant understand it really the line 44 itself is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so the main activity itself is here below

> MainActivity

```
package com.example.whatsappclone;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private TabLayout myTablayout;
    private TabsAccessorAdapter myTabAccessorAdapter;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        myTablayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        myTablayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);

        myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
        myTabAccessorAdapter = new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabAccessorAdapter);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsAppClone");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else{
            VerifyUserExistance();
        }
    }

    private void VerifyUserExistance() {
        String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if ((dataSnapshot.child("name").exists()))
              {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              else{
                 SendUserToSettingsActivity();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_logout_option){
           mAuth.signOut();
           SendUserToLoginActivity();
         }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_settings_option){
            SendUserToSettingsActivity();
        }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_create_group_option){
            RequestNewGroup();
        }

        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.main_find_friends_option){

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void RequestNewGroup() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialog);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Group Name :");

        final EditText groupNameField = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        groupNameField.setHint("e.g Class Of 2K14");
        builder.setView(groupNameField);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String groupName = groupNameField.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(groupName)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please write Group name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                  CreateNewGroup(groupName);
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    private void CreateNewGroup(final String groupName) {
        RootRef.child("Groups").child(groupName).setValue("")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, groupName +"group is successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }


    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToSettingsActivity() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        settingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Also below is the activity_main Xml

> Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">


   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">


      <include
          layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
          android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
          >
      </include>

      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="12sp"
          android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

      </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <androidx.core.view.ViewPager
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/main_tabs_pager"
       android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">

      <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
          android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_gravity="top"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:textColor="#fff"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

      </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>

   </androidx.core.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435658/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist/48462365

Answer (score 0):

Looks like com.android.support:design is missing from you dependencies, open app build.gradle and add that

Comment: nop i migrated to android X since so the design library isnt there anymore so i dont know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multidex? Check related configs here:
[mulitdex doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)