# Flutter android App crashes when trying to debug after signing release

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, apk

I am new to flutter and am building a flutter app as part of a school project. My team and I are building an ios, android, and web app releases and I am tasked with generating and signing my app bundle to release in google play. I was able to successfully sign the bundle and upload the project.  I am unable to test the release build on an emulator but that is another issue that could possibly be related.

On to the point, I am having an issue now debugging my app. There was no issue before renaming and configuring the build type, I was just using the default application ID and running the debugger in VScode. My app seems to build successfully (I think because I get no errors) but it does not install on the emulator correctly. I get a popup notification on the emulation that unfortunately the app keeps closing. In the capture logs I see " Waiting for observatory port to be available...".

I have reset the emulator, flutter clean and rebuild. I have tried running/cleaning/building in android studio (debug) to no avail.

Here are the capture logs. I didn't include them all since it seems like the app is building correctly.

```
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=177)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" (Raw: "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=182)
                     E: action (line=183)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" (Raw: "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")
                 E: service (line=187)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=191)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: provider (line=197)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.firebaseinitprovider" (Raw: "com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                 E: meta-data (line=203)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f080004
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [   +6 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on Android SDK built for x86.
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [        ] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.sensationalscience.sensational_science
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +44 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.sensationalscience.sensational_science
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [ +215 ms] package:com.sensationalscience.sensational_science
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.sha1
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +24 ms] 2ef7da51e6c1f4f4170671be4372471e59f61ee6
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [        ] Installing APK.
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +16 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <==            Version 29.0.6-6198805
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <==            Installed as C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [        ] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"bc8e3997-0174-4387-ae07-3b6f69cdc04d","id":"1","progressId":null,"message":"Installing build\\app\\outputs\\apk\\app.apk..."}}]
[12:19:52 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +17 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install -t -r C:\Users\Lauren\Documents\School\467\sensational_science\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [+3493 ms] Performing Streamed Install
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <==            Success
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"bc8e3997-0174-4387-ae07-3b6f69cdc04d","id":"1","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell echo -n cc0ff10c7a448e68c958b5ace7858fca4554ee4e > /data/local/tmp/sky.com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.sha1
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +31 ms] Android SDK built for x86 startApp
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\Lauren\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true --ez start-paused true com.sensationalscience.sensational_science/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.MainActivity
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [  +95 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.sensationalscience.sensational_science/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[12:19:56 PM] [FlutterRun] [Info] [Flutter] <== [        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
Tue May 05 2020 [12:23:20 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] Log file ended
```

Here is my app level build.gradle. Please take note of my buildtypes. I am not sure these are configured correctly. I followed https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android but their explanation of how to set up the build types was limited.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // connection to firebase 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

 def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
android {


    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.sensationalscience.sensational_science"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }


//**Note in my app I have the correct key info I just replaced the information here.
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['xx']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['xx']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['C:\\Keystore\\xx'] ? file(keystoreProperties['xx']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['xx']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {

            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}



flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2' // connect to firebase analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0' // connect to firebase authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2' // connect to firebase coud firestore
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // allow more than 64k methods with multidex enabling
}
```

Here is my android Manifest. I am wondering if the MainActivy is the issue. I am not quite sure where/what exactly that file is and at the end of the capture logs there is a a reference to it at starting Intent. 
``

```
package="com.sensationalscience.sensational_science">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="sensational_science"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Add UCrop Activity for image cropping (MPJ 4/21/20)-->
    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Here is my build.gradle. I am getting this error Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Lauren.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.2
Please read the following process output to find out more:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heapJava(0)

```
       buildscript {
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
            }

            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
                classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // for connecting to firebase
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
            }
        }

        rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
        subprojects {
            project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        }
        subprojects {
            project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
        }

        task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
        }
```

edit: I added to the capture logs

edit: Adding android studio crash details:

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2020-05-05 13:37:49.148 13524-13524/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sensationalscience.sensational_science, PID: 13524
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sensationalscience.sensational_science/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sensationalscience.sensational_science.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.sensationalscience.sensational_science-TWyC0kIWuswGoy1G-VAtCQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Try to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest file.

Comment: Got the same issue. I debugged in android studio and got a more helpful response. I will edit my post with it.

Comment: That is better, Instant run could be the problem, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435658/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist

Comment: I couldn't find a solution on that page but I did notice that  Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.  is deifferent from what it installs. Notices its an apk not a debug apk
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...

Comment: when I run a debug on the master branch(have not merge changes yet) It correctly builds the debug apk then installs the debug-apk. I wonder why it is not installing the debug apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. When I changed the application name/ID I accidently changed the MainActivity.java class name. I changed changed the class name to MainActivity from Sensational Science.

```
package com.sensationalscience.sensational_science

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```