# ClassNotFoundException on Android API 26 for MainActivity (working with API 30)

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-8.0-oreo, android-10.0

I have a Android Studio project which I tested on API 30 and is working fine. Now I tried running it on API 26 (which is the minimum SDK version I set for the project) and I can't get the app to start.
Both times I used an emulated Pixel 3a and one external device.

---

### Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.main.xyz, PID: 9389
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.main.xyz/com.main.xyz.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.main.xyz.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.main.xyz.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.main.xyz-rZkYLBaLo3gdkb7oCChonQ==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
            ... 6 more
```

### My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
//Called by Button
public void login(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Uebersicht.class);
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

### My build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.main.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.0'

}
```

### My build.grade (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### And my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main.xyz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Uebersicht"
            android:label="" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProductActivity"
            android:label="" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddActivity"
            android:label=""/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScanActivity"
            android:label="" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

I've been looking for a solution for quite a while now. As I'm pretty new to Android all help is deeply appreciated. If you can provide it I'd really to have an explaination to my problem as well as a solution to be able to understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: show you proguard. Because of  `minifyEnabled true`

Comment: proguard is all commented out. minifyEnabled true was just once thing I tried, doesn't change whether it works or doesn't work

Comment: then set `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: okay, thanks (but still doesn't start)

Comment: clean-rebuild-run.  if different error logs come then inform

Comment: what do you mean by clean-rebuild-run? Just create a new project and copy classes etc?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the dexing error description and found [another question regarding java 8 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435658/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist). Implementing

```
compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

and

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
```

into the app's build.gradle file solved the problem.

[More information here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a problem with dexing , so try to add this library in your dependencies gradle , so do as following  :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add this library 
}
```

and here add this code

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.main.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        multiDexEnabled true // add this line of code 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly doesn't help it.. Error message stays the same as well

Comment: In your logcat error , can you click at the error and see what line it takes you to ?